# Kubernetes check port opened

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

My container use tomcat application server and take about less than 10 second to open port 8080 .
is there any way on kubernetes LoadBalancer to check port opened before forward requests to that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this document :
[Configure Liveness, Readiness and Startup Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)